# PHP5 with old PHP4 code

Tags: php, apache, deprecated

My friend wants me to tweak his website. But I'm getting the errors

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\toolmanager\toolmanager\index.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _REQUEST in C:\xampp\htdocs\toolmanager\toolmanager\includes\classloader_platform.php on line 154

when I try to run the code on apache with PHP5. Here's the code:

```
        require("includes/classloader_platform.php");
line 7->$classloader =& NEW classloader('0','30',$_GET,'1');
        $classloader->initialize($classloader);

line 154-> function __construct($cache=false,$cache_lifecycle=false,$_REQUEST,$template_parser=false) {
           ini_set("memory_limit","200M");
           //globalize _REQUEST
           $this->_REQUEST=$_REQUEST;
...
```

I think it's because he wrote it by PHP4 standards so would it be better to switch apache to PHP4 or are there some simple fixes for these errors?

Comment: rename your local `$_REQUEST` in the constructor to some other things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do **not** revert to PHP 4. It is old and unsupported.

For *"Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference"*, just remove the `&`. It's redundant.

```
$classloader = NEW classloader(...);
```

For *"Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable*", rename the function argument `$_REQUEST` to something else such as `$REQUEST`, then rename the subsequent occurrences of it within the function. You can't have a function argument with the same name as a superglobal.

```
function __construct($cache=false,$cache_lifecycle=false,$REQUEST,$template_parser=false) {
    // ...
    $this->_REQUEST=$REQUEST;
    // ...
```

Comment: That worked but now I'm getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_fetch()" from this: "$hits=apc_fetch("_STATS".$key);"
Is apc_fetch() not supported anymore?

Comment: `apc_fetch()` is still definitely part of the APC extension. Is APC enabled?

Comment: Probably not. I looked in the "php.ini" file for ";extension=apc.so" but I couldn't find it. Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: No, that's the way to enable it, but you probably need to compile it first. I don't think it comes in the standard distribution.

Comment: @CharlesMurray Come to think of it, if you've installed PHP via your systems package manager (e.g., `apt` or `yum`), there might simply be a `php-apc` package you could install instead.

Comment: I installed pecl and when I did "pecl install apc" it said "WARNING: php_bin C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe appears to have a suffix \.\php.exe, but cofig variable php_suffix does not match" and then errored with "The DSP APC.dsp does not exist"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14019/discussion-between-charles-murray-and-wiseguy)